# Oracle Export Very Large Tables

Tags: oracle, export, large-data, large-data-volumes

I try to export a table with 1.8 Billion Rows and 1.5TB os size not sucess for now.

```
exp xxx/xxxx@server file=tabela_grande.txt direct=y  tables=('TB_DM_HORI_CLUSTER_CANAL_01')
```

I'm trying EXP command but it's taking too long. About 10 hours and not over yet.
Does anyone have any tips for exporting and later importing faster?
Thank you so much!

Comment: EXP is deprecated. Look at Data Pump https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Comment: +1; when I compared EXP to EXPDP, the difference was *huge* so - nothing to lose, but possibly much to get. Try it.